# Minimize a differece that has to be positive

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following optimization:

mnimize: obj(x) = f(x) - constant

sbj.to: lb < x < hb

sbj.to: f(x) - constant >= 0

I have the feeling that this is not the most convenient way to put the optimization problem. Is there another way which might be more convenient computationally?
Till now I tried to modify the objective for example using obj(x) = (f(x) - constant)^2, which permit me to avoid the second constraint. But it gives me some convergence problems depending on the value of the constant. Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two other possible approaches - not sure whether they are any better, but that is:

1. If [f(x) - constant]^2 gives you convergence issues (not sure why?), try and replace it with abs(f(x) - constant). Warning: the abs() function is not always the best behaved, sometimes it confuses some optimization algorithms
2. In your objective function, if (f(x) - constant) becomes negative, return a big value - proportional to how much it becomes negative. Otherwise return the normal difference.

Comment: I tried the absolute value already but was not ideal considering that i can calculate an analytical gradient. I'm also not sure why it gives convergence issues. I'm investigating it and will come back if i find an answer. Regarding the big value if it's negative, you mean something like a penalty function?

Comment: Yes, like a penalty function. It works very well in many instances.